# Unable to query the data from the Oracle database table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that returns the following output:

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBER_ACHIEVEMENTS;
--------------------------------------------------------
| CATEGORY_ID | MEMBER_ID | MILESTONE | MILESTONE_DATE |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   GOLF      |    1001   |   WINNER  |   23-JAN-2019  |
|   GOLF      |    1001   |   SECOND  |   12-AUG-2019  |
|   GOLF      |    1001   |   THIRD   |   18-DEC-2018  |
|   GOLF      |    1002   |   WINNER  |   11-FEB-2018  |
|   GOLF      |    1003   |   SECOND  |   17-APR-2018  |
|   GOLF      |    1003   |   WINNER  |   30-MAR-2019  |
|   GOLF      |    1004   |   SECOND  |   10-JUN-2017  |
|   GOLF      |    1004   |   WINNER  |   15-JAN-2019  |
|   GOLF      |    1004   |   SECOND  |   19-FEB-2019  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to display the CATEGORY_ID and MEMBER_ID for all the members who have a MILESTONE = 'WINNER' and have another milestone with a MILESTONE_DATE greater (later) than the date of the MILESTONE = 'WINNER' and MILESTONE <>'WINNER'.

The output I'm expecting is:

```
---------------------------
| CATEGORY_ID | MEMBER_ID |
---------------------------
|   GOLF      |    1001   |
|   GOLF      |    1004   |
---------------------------
```

The query I tried is:

```
SELECT CATEGORY_ID, MEMBER_ID FROM MEMBER_ACHIEVEMENTS WHERE MEMBER_ID IN 
(
 SELECT CATEGORY_ID, MEMBER_ID FROM MEMBER_ACHIEVEMENTS WHERE MILESTONE_DATE >
 (
  SELECT CATEGORY_ID, MEMBER_ID, MILESTONE_DATE FROM MEMBER_ACHIEVEMENTS WHERE MILESTONE='WINNER'
 )
);
```

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me fix this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation to see if there is another date later than the most recent "winner" -- which is what I think you are asking:

```
select category_id, member_id
from member_achievements ma
group by category_id, member_id
having max(milestone_date) > max(case when milestone = 'WINNER' then milestone_date end) ;
```

Alternatively, you might want that there is a non-winner after the first winner:

```
select category_id, member_id
from member_achievements ma
group by category_id, member_id
having (max(case when milestone <> 'WINNER' then milestone_date end) >
        min(case when milestone = 'WINNER' then milestone_date end)
       );
```